# ASP:Chart number localised formatting without changing culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, number-formatting, aspchart

I have an ASP:Chart control in a web application (ASP.Net). They are used to display some basic accounting information, like so:

[image: Lovely chart]

However, I want to be able to change the decimal separator to a comma, for display in other countries that used the comma, e.g. -28606.62 should display as -28606,62.

I know I can change the current culture in the code behind for the page, and this will format the numbers correctly, however I am reluctant to do this as this will change the culture for the thread/page, and thus any calculations etc that may be done during the life of the page may screw up.

Is there another way of specifying the decimal separator on the ASP:Chart control?

I've tried playing with the **LabelStyle.Format** property, but this doesn't allow you to change the separators, only the format of the number.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [FormatNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.formatnumber(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the chart control as shown below:

```
yourChart.FormatNumber += Chart_FormatLocalisedNumber;
```

And your event code:

```
     private void Chart_FormatLocalisedNumber(object sender, FormatNumberEventArgs e)
     {
            e.LocalizedValue = e.Value.ToString("N2", YourFormatProvider);
     }
```

Inside the event you can set the e.LocalizedValue to what ever you want and this will be what is displayed on the chart.

In the example above i used a [Standard Numeric Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) and passed in a format provider (such as new Culture("nl-NL")) which has the "," as a decimal symbol.